# Include images in RStudio notebook with knitr::include_graphics()

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am quite excited about the upcoming RStudio notebooks (available in the [preview version of RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/). For a short overview click [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html)). However, I am encountering some **difficulties with including images**.

In Rmarkdown, I can include images like this:

````
--- 
title: "This works"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='10%'}
library(knitr)
knitr::include_graphics('https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/RStudio-Ball.png')
```
````

[image: RStudio Logo]

However, when I want to do the same in a notebook (note the change from `html_document` to `html_notebook`), I no longer get an image:

````
--- 
title: "This does not work"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='10%'}
knitr::include_graphics('https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/RStudio-Ball.png')
```
````

[image: There should be a Logo here]

(When I use an image in the same folder as my notebook, I simply get the name of that image, just as is the case with the link to the external image).

**My question: is there a way to display the image also in the notebook *(update:) inside a rmarkdown code-chunk*?**

**Please note**: I want to use r-code to include the image. I do not want to include images with standard markdown (`![image description](path/to/image)`), which works in both the notebook and the regular rmarkdown document. I also do not want to use html. My hope would be that using r-code to include the image would render the image in the notebook.

**Edit**: One difference between regular Rmarkdown files and notebooks is that notebooks are "previewed" and not knit:

[image: preview button for notebook]

Comment: u want to use `r code` or `rmarkdown` syntax to get an image? Please confirm

Comment: I want to use `r-code` ,ideally `knitr::include_graphics()`

Comment: apologies, I misread your statement. I would like to include the image inside a r-markdown code-chunk

Comment: Oh, let me see. So you want to read a image inside r chunk and when through r markdown when you knit r notebook, the image should be there? Is that right?

Comment: I think so. Just to clarify: I do not knit the notebook, but preview it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to try out the notebooks. There is a roundabout way you can do this today; just make a plot and draw the image on it.

```
download.file("https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/RStudio-Ball.png", "RStudio-Ball.png")
library("png")
ball <- readPNG("RStudio-Ball.png", native = TRUE)
plot(0:1, 0:1, type = "n", ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
rasterImage(ball, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

It's a bit of a hack, though, so we just added support for `knitr::include_graphics`. It'll be in tomorrow's daily (0.99.1272 or later).